# How to find the v(t)?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, inductor, steady-state

can someone help me in here.

Find the V(t) when t = 2,5ms and knowing that i(t) = Icos(wt).
R= 50ohms, L=100mH, I=2A, w=100π rad/s
[image: circuit]

Like I know that Z = 50 + j10π = 59,05∠32,14°
And v(t) = Z*i(t) = 59,05∠32,14° * 2∠0° = 118,10∠32,14°

v(2,5ms) = 118,10*cos(100π*2,5m + 32,14) = 99V

But the answer in my book is 26,3V so I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: You have to solve the transient not the steady state ac situation.

Comment: I still don't get the expected answer when I fix this, but in your last equation you have part of the argument of cos() expressed in radians and part of it expressed in degrees. I agree with Andy that it would be simpler to just solve this in the time domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\$ v(t)=L\large\frac{di(t)}{dt}\small+Ri(t)\$

\$ v(t)=L\large \frac{d}{dt}\normalsize 2\:cos(100\pi t)+50(2\:cos(100\pi t))\$

\$ v(t)=0.1\times (-200\pi \:sin(100\pi t))+100\:cos(100\pi t)\$

\$ v(t)=-20\pi \:sin(100\pi t)+100\:cos(100\pi t)\$

we have: \$100\pi t=100\pi\times 0.0025=\large \frac{\pi}{4}\small\equiv \normalsize 45^o\$

hence, \$ v(0.0025)=-\large \frac{20\pi}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{100}{\sqrt{2}}\normalsize=26.28\: V\$